# JSON request not working correctly in jQuery Each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, foreach

I am using the code below to retrieve the latitude and longitude of a given location if the value has been changed for each div containing the class `.event`.

The problem I'm having is that only two outcomes occur from this code:

- The values returned from one JSON request are used for every `lat` and `lon` variable
- The variables `lat` and `lon` remain exactly the same, as if they were remain untouched so the JSON values are not replaced.

Below is the code I am using:

```
    $(".button").click(function(){

            data = "";
            $(".event").each(function(){

                original = $(this).find(".address").data("original");
                location = $(this).find(".address").html();
                lat = $(this).find(".lat").html();
                lon = $(this).find(".lon").html();

                if (original !== location) {

                    $.getJSON( "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q="+location+"&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1", function(result) {
                        lat = result[0].lat;
                        lon = result[0].lon;
                    });

                }

                data = data + randomNumber() + ": " + lat + " " + lon + ",";

            });

            $(".data").val(data);
            $(".form").submit();

    });
```

The variable `data` will contain the `lat` and `lon` for each div containing the class `event`. The values will remain the same unless the address has been changed by the user, at which point they will be retrieved again via a JSON request.

The form should then be submitted.

How could I fix this? Thank you

Comment: `$.getJSON` is asynchronous. You're setting `data` before the callback functions execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getJSON` is asynchronous, you can't refer to the result outside the callback function. And you don't want to submit the form until *all* the AJAX requests are done.

`$.getJSON()` returns a `Deferred`. You can make an array of all of them, and use `$.when()` to wait for them.

```
$(".button").click(function() {

  var promises = [];
  var data = "";
  $(".event").each(function() {

    var original = $(this).find(".address").data("original");
    var location = $(this).find(".address").html();
    var lat = $(this).find(".lat").html();
    var lon = $(this).find(".lon").html();

    if (original !== location) {
      promises.push($.getJSON("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=" + location + "&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1", function(result) {
        var lat = result[0].lat;
        var lon = result[0].lon;
        data += randomNumber() + ": " + lat + " " + lon + ",";
      }));

    } else {
      data += randomNumber() + ": " + lat + " " + lon + ",";
    }

  });
  $.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {

    $(".data").val(data);
    $(".form").submit();
  });

});
```

Note that the order of the values in `data` is unpredictable, since AJAX requests don't necessarily return in the same order they were sent.

You should also get in the habit of declaring your variables as local with `var` (or `let` in ES6).

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Also is having `var lat/lon` underneath the JSON request required since it's already been declared as a variable? The code was kinda buggy with certain events having the same address so I had to remove that.

Comment: It's best to avoid sharing variables between different functions unless you actually need to. There's no need for the AJAX callback function to use the same `lat/lon` variables as the iteration function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should call `$.getJSON` concurrently then deal all result while got all of them.

If `$.getJSON` is not necessary for a location, you can create a immediate resolving deferred/promise to simulate a async call. So that we can deal with the same type of results (jQuery Promise Object).

Here is code (not test) and comments:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    // data = "";
    // unnecessary

    // $(".event").each(function() {
    // use map to get promise objects for every ".event"
    var promises = $(".event").map(function() {
        original = $(this).find(".address").data("original");
        location = $(this).find(".address").html();
        // lat = $(this).find(".lat").html();
        // lon = $(this).find(".lon").html();
        // not need here

        if (original !== location) {
            return $.getJSON("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=" + location + "&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1", function(result) {
                lat = result[0].lat;
                lon = result[0].lon;
            });
        } else {
            // make value type same as json, it's a array of { lat, lon }
            return $.Deferred().resolve([{
                lat: $(this).find(".lat").html(),
                lon: $(this).find(".lon").html()
            }]).promise();
        }

        // data = data + randomNumber() + ": " + lat + " " + lon + ",";
        // do it later, after all promise resolved.
    });

    $.when.apply(null, promises)
        .done(function() {
            // convert arguments to a array
            var args = [].slice.apply(arguments);
            data = args
                .map(function(models) {
                    // convert each model to a string
                    var model = models[0];
                    return randomNumber() + ": " + model.lat + " " + lon;
                })
                // join each part with separator ','
                .join(",");

            // while got data, deal with it
            $(".data").val(data);
            $(".form").submit();
        });
});
```